# Android parse nested json array (one to many relationship)

Tags: java, android, json

Hi guys I have a problem parsing my nested json array. This is my sample json response:

```
{
"SUCCESS": true,
"DATA": [
  {
    "ShowData": [
      {
        "ShowTitle": "Episode 1",
        "Category": "Comedy"
      },
      {
        "ShowTitle": "Episode 1a",
        "Category": "Drama"
      },
      {
        "ShowTitle": "Mr. Right",
        "Category": "Musical"
      },
      {
        "ShowTitle": "The Making",
        "Category": "Talk"
      },
      {
        "ShowTitle": "Presscon",
        "Category": "Comedy"
      },
      {
        "ShowTitle": "Presscon 2",
        "Category": "Drama"
      },
      {
        "ShowTitle": "Episode 2",
        "Category": "Comedy"
      },
      {
        "ShowTitle": "Episode 2",
        "Category": "Drama"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

}
This is what I've tried so far:

Activity:

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> showsList
                                =      Parser.getShowsResponseBody(response);

                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
                        Set<String> titles = new HashSet<>();

                        for(HashMap<String, String> map : showsList) {
                            if(titles.add(map.get("Category"))) {
                                result.add(map);
                            }
                        }
```

Parser:

```
public static List<Show> getShowsResponseBody(Response response) {
BufferedReader reader = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getBody().in()));
    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String result = sb.toString();

List<Show> list = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("DATA");
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray arr = json_data.getJSONArray("ShowData");
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject innerData = arr.getJSONObject(j);

            Show show = new Show(); // Create Object here

         show.setShowTitle(innerData.getString("ShowTitle"));
         show.setCategory(innerData.getString("Category"));
         list.add(show); // Finally adding the model to List
        }

    }

}
```

My expected output is:

```
  Comedy: Episode 1, Presscon, Episode 2
  Drama: Episode 1a, Presscon 2, Episode 2
  Musical: Mr. Right
  Talk: The Making
```

But when I run the app, it's displaying all the records in all category. What seem to be wrong with my code? I already used HashSet to remove duplicate objects but it's still the same. Any help would be gladly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_world_show_item, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvShowName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvShowName);
        viewHolder.btViewAllShows = (MyButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btViewAllShows);
        viewHolder.rvWorldShows = (RecyclerView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rvWorldShows);
        viewHolder.llBackground = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llBackground);
        viewHolder.showsManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        viewHolder.rvWorldShows.setLayoutManager(viewHolder.showsManager);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(position % 2 == 0) {
        viewHolder.llBackground.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.main_blue_pressed));
    } else {
        viewHolder.llBackground.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.main_blue));
    }

  viewHolder.tvShowName.setText(result.get(Constants.SHOW_CATEGORY));
    display(viewHolder.rvWorldShows, map, mList);
    return convertView;

}
```

Comment: why is the methond getShowsResponseBody in your Parse class return List<Show>, but it's  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> in your activity ?

Comment: Could you please provide the code of WorldShow? I the class Show is just a pojo with title and category property.

Comment: @Weibo sorry that's a Show class not WorldShow. I mistyped.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes then, how about return value of  method getShowsResponseBody ?

Comment: @Weibo getShowsResponseBody is under my Parser Class.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes  in your activity,  the return value is : ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> showsList
                                =      Parser.getShowsResponseBody(response);  but in your parse, your return value is List<Show>, this made me confused.

Comment: @Weibo can you check my post? Anyway, this is my activity: ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> showsList
                                =      Parser.getShowsResponseBody(response);

                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
                        Set<String> titles = new HashSet<>();

                        for(HashMap<String, String> map : showsList) {
                            if(titles.add(map.get("Category"))) {
                                result.add(map);
                            }
                        }

Comment: Maybe we are not talk in the same paper, what I concerned is that: the method call in your activity has different return value with you defined in you Parse class. can you compile correct your pc? I tried the code in my ide, but   it compile failed.

Comment: @Weibo just add closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

Change in below code :

```
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("DATA");
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject innerData = jArray .getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray arr = json_data.getJSONArray("ShowData");
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject jbj= arr.getJSONObject(j);

            Show show = new Show(); // Create Object here

         show.setShowTitle(jbj.getString("ShowTitle"));
         show.setCategory(jbj.getString("Category"));
         list.add(show); // Finally adding the model to List
        }
}
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Hi there's nothing wrong with my code. I've updated it to DATA. My problem is that all shows are displayed in all categories

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainClass{

    private boolean SUCESS;
    private List<MainClass> DATA;
    private List<SubClass> showData;

    private class SubClass{
        private String ShowTitle;
        private String Category
    }

}
```

use DTO Class so that it will be very easy to handle complex json objects. You can parse your json by using single line.

```
MainClass obj = new Gson().fromJson(result , MainClass.class);
```

Comment: Thanks! But we are not required to use GSON or any 3rd party libraries. The problem will be how to display this via Adapter.

Comment: Where are setting your adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the response you model class hierarchy would be.

```
Class Response{
boolean Success;
 private List<DATA> dataList;
}

Class DATA{
 private List<ShowData> showDataList;
}

Class ShowDataList{
String ShowTitle;
String Category;
}
```

Comment: THis is the same model I have

Comment: what does your display method do? I think you are duplicating items in getView